# How to click a link from list selenium2

Tags: java, webdriver, html-lists, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 and I want to click an 'invite' link for Name3. How can I do that?

here is the html code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="511565484">
        <img src="pic1">Name1</label>
        <a class="button_green sendInvite" href="javascript:;" title="Invite">Invite</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for="535963597">
        <img src="pic2">Name2</label>
        <a class="button_green sendInvite" href="javascript:;" title="Invite">Invite</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for="561708219">
        <img src="pic3">Name3</label>
        <a class="button_green sendInvite" href="javascript:;" title="Invite">Invite</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems likely it can only be done with XPath:

```
//label[text()='Name3']/following-sibling::a
```

Comment: or better yet: `//label[@src='pic3']/following-sibling::a`

Answer (score 0):

element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[()text='Name3']/a"));
element2.click();

Answer (score 0):

If XPATH isn't the most usable thing for you, you can always do something like this (Ruby implementation of Webdriver... but it's all the same):

```
invite_links = driver.find_elements(:class_name, "sendInvite")
```

invite_links now contains an array of all matches, so your next step is pretty easy:

```
invite_links[2].click()
```

Or the way I'd do it:

```
driver.find_elements(:class_name, "sendInvite")[2].click
```

This is a little easier for me to read than XPATH, because I don't use it that often.